# Mixing time of a random walk

Tags: graph-theory, random-walk, mixing

I have a very basic doubt about mixing time of the graph. I want to know how the mixing time reduces as I add edge to a connected graph $G$. Is there a possibility of the mixing time of the random walker to increase in a graph if the edges are added in some adversarial fashion? (my intuition says the mixing time should decrease).

I would be very grateful if someone could point to some resource or help me understand the change in mixing time as the graph adds one edge at a time.

Thanks!

Comment: Consider a path of length $n$, which has mixing time $O(n^2)$, and two cliques of size $n/3$ connected by a path of length $n/3$, which has mixing time $\Omega(n^3)$. While the latter graph can be constructed by adding edges to the former graph, its mixing time is much larger.